# Move input inside label with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I move the input inside the `<label>` tag, so that it would be `<label><input></label>` using jQuery. I need to target all the answers within the select-option set.

```html
<div class=”select-option”>
<div>
 <input id="[0]_Actual_Answer_1" name="[0]_Actual_Answer_1" type="radio" value="IZWE">
 <label for="[0]_Actual_Answer_1">HELLO WORLD</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input id="[0]_Actual_Answer_2" name="[0]_Actual_Answer_2" type="radio" value="IZWE">
 <label for="[0]_Actual_Answer_2">HELLO WORLD 2</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input id="[0]_Actual_Answer_3" name="[0]_Actual_Answer_3" type="radio" value="IZWE">
 <label for="[0]_Actual_Answer_3">HELLO WORLD 3</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input id="[0]_Actual_Answer_4" name="[0]_Actual_Answer_4" type="radio" value="IZWE">
 <label for="[0]_Actual_Answer_4">HELLO WORLD 4</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *I need to target all the answers within the select-option set* But all radio is in `.select-option`. Do you mean in root of it?

Comment: The `for` value seems correct for the labels, so why would it matter if the inputs are inside the labels? If you want the inputs after the text, just move them below the labels?

Comment: `<label><input></label>` <. you want to remove the text that's already there ?

Comment: Note that you have invalid quotes around  `<div class=”select-option”>`

Comment: Anyway `$('.select-option label').append(function() {return $(this).prev('input')});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes `<div class=”select-option”>` are incorrect! Use `"`
Than for the jQuery part:

```js
$("label[for*='[0]_Actual_Answer']").prepend(function(){
  return $(this).prev("input");
});
```

```css
label{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-option">
  <div>
    <input id="[0]_Actual_Answer_1" name="[0]_Actual_Answer_1" type="radio" value="IZWE">
    <label for="[0]_Actual_Answer_1">HELLO WORLD</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="[0]_Actual_Answer_2" name="[0]_Actual_Answer_2" type="radio" value="IZWE">
    <label for="[0]_Actual_Answer_2">HELLO WORLD 2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="[0]_Actual_Answer_3" name="[0]_Actual_Answer_3" type="radio" value="IZWE">
    <label for="[0]_Actual_Answer_3">HELLO WORLD 3</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="[0]_Actual_Answer_4" name="[0]_Actual_Answer_4" type="radio" value="IZWE">
    <label for="[0]_Actual_Answer_4">HELLO WORLD 4</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you may be after is something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select-option input').each(function() { //Get every input in the "select-option" div
     var t = $(this);
     var l = t.siblings('label'); //Find the closest label
     t.detach().appendTo(l);
  });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/40zxez4a/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `prepend(function)`

```
$('.select-option label[for*=Actual_Answer]').prepend(function(){
    return $(this).prev("input")
});
```